# Retrieve data from a Card in Oracle Apex

Tags: javascript, jquery, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a Card Regions which display some of my tables. I want the cards to each redirect to a certain page based on a number (the number labelled has "page_table" is the page number it will redirect on).

Here's the Query of the Cards Region

```
SELECT table_name,
REPLACE(SUBSTR(table_name, 8),'_','-') AS nom_table, -- here, i remove the "INV_TB_" prefix from my tables
CASE
WHEN table_name = 'INV_TB_BATIMENT' THEN 11
WHEN table_name = 'INV_TB_CATEGORIE' THEN 12
WHEN table_name = 'INV_TB_DEPARTEMENT' THEN 13
WHEN table_name = 'INV_TB_SERVICE' THEN 14
WHEN table_name = 'INV_TB_POSSEDER' THEN 15
WHEN table_name = 'INV_TB_SITUER' THEN 16
WHEN table_name = 'INV_TB_ETAGE_BUREAU' THEN 16 END AS page_table --this is the column where i define the page number for each table
from cat 
WHERE table_name LIKE 'INV_TB_%'
AND table_name <> 'INV_TB_AMORTISSEMENT'
AND table_name <> 'INV_TB_ARTICLE_LOGS'
AND table_name <> 'INV_TB_ARTICLE_DASHBOARD'
AND table_name <> 'INV_TB_DOCUMENT'
AND table_name <> 'INV_TB_VILLE'
AND table_name <> 'INV_TB_DASHBOARD'
AND table_name <> 'INV_TB_ARTICLE'
```

Here's the result :

[image: result of the card region]

---

For each one of them, I want to be able to retrieve the number in the little square on the left :

[image: icon and badge]

---

Which will be used to redirect the user to the specific page in Link and Target of the Cards :

[image]

---

I've thought about using an Hidden Item which will receive the value of the square when I click on the card, maybe using JavaScript or jQuery ? Or is there a more easy way to retrieve the value of the custom column "page_table" based on the card I'm clicking on ?

My last solution is to create a table which will contains the name of the real tables, with the page number in real columns, but I would like to know first if my first idea is possible

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Comment: Have you tried using the syntax #PAGE_TABLE# ? That is the syntax to reference report column subsitutions

Comment: I tried to add #PAGE_TABLE# as you said in "Page" in "Target" just like in the 3rd picture but the value is not saved and stay empty. Did I do it wrong ?

Comment: Apologies, I just tested and it's the other syntax - see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the cards region, the substitution syntax for columns is `&COLUMN_NAME.` so in your case `&PAGE_TABLE.` should work. Can you give that a try ?

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot ! The answer was just in front of my eyes but didn't see it :-) Thank you very much !!!

Comment: Happy to hear it helped :)